# Can I make a dropbox folder public by using python client?

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using `dropbox` for one of my application where a user can connect their dropbox folders.

Usage is such that a user can create links among the files of a folder and many more. But the problem is the moment when I stored the file information in my application, the file media information is stored with a key `expires`. So obviously I wont be able to use the link next time once the expiry time is met.

One way is to generate the media information every time the user is selecting a thumbnail from my application, as I already have metadata of the file.

But is there any other way (i.e by using `python client` or `API`) that I can make a folder public when a user selects it to connect with my application.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right thing to do is to generate a media link each time you need it.

Is there a reason you don't like that solution?

Comment: Hi smarx,
The only reason I was sceptical in doing that was it would be a bit slow. But no other options seems to be available, so I am already doing same stuff. 

Any way thanks a lot for devoting your time. :)

Comment: I'm curious whether it *is* actually slow. What's your experience so far?

Comment: it is slow.

for 30kb of images, each of them being almost 3kb it takes 30 seconds. but once cached the latency reduces

Comment: Generating the media link takes 30 seconds? Or generating 10 media links takes 30 seconds (30KB/3KB)? I wouldn't think that the size of the file would have any effect on how long it takes to create a media link.

Comment: generating 10 media links it takes 30 secs.

Comment: There is, actually, an alternative, which is to crate a share link (which doesn't expire) and then convert it every time you need it. You do that by changing the domain: replace "www.dropbox.com" with "dl.dropboxusercontent.com" to get a direct link to the file. See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en. Of course, you'll need to handle the case when a user decides to stop sharing the files. (Users can see what they're sharing at https://www.dropbox.com/share.)